# Vue js - Dynamically add form inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

I'm trying to create some dynamic input fields in my vue js app.
I've googled a bit to find the best way, and I've ended up with the following code:

```html
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 mt-1 mb-1">
                <a class="text-uppercase text-decoration-none text-dark" href="#" @click.prevent="addField">
                    <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
                    Add device properties
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mt-1 mb-1" v-for="inputs in fieldsCounter" :key="inputs">
                <div class="input-group">    
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase rounded-0 me-1" v-model="deviceDetails.fieldName" placeholder="Field Name" @change="log">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase rounded-0 ms-1" v-model="deviceDetails.fieldValue" placeholder="Field Value" @change="log">
                </div>
            </div>
```

```js
        addField(){
            this.fieldsCounter++
            console.log(this.fieldsCounter)
            this.deviceDetails.push({})
        },
```

The problem is that when I add a new field after the first one, the `v-model` will set the same field values inside the created field. How I can solve this little problem?

Comment: Without the real URL it's going to be rather hard to tell anything specific about your issue.

Comment: Looks like a repost  of [Puppeteer - How to extract data attribute from same id or class selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75653214/puppeteer-how-to-extract-data-attribute-from-same-id-or-class-selectors?noredirect=1#comment133477598_75653214). Same response... without the site, I can't help. I'd avoid these recorders and [super-hardcoded selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors). It's no surprise those break. If even a single div or class name in the document changes, it fails.